# Type Library WideString to String

Tags: string, widestring, typelib

I have a dll built in C# and I consume it using Delphi XE2 by typelibrary. Works correctly but I have a function that return a WideString and should be returned a name with special chars like 'çãé' (i from Brazil) but the result is "???".

How can I handle this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi, simply:

1) Declare your variable as [WideString](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE/en/String_Types) or [PWideString](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE/en/System.PWideString) (pointer)

2) Convert to (Delphi) "String"

It should be as easy as that!

If that doesn't help - or if I've understood your problem incorrectly - please update your question and post the relevant Delphi XE2 code.

Comment: thanks for awswer, but could you tell the source code?